# Decide if Turing machine's language contains either a or b string

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

during school exercises we worked on decidability problems and there was one I don't really understand. We were provided with solution and explanation regarding this exercise but still I need more guidance.

The problem is:

Proof that 
$L = \{ <M> | M$ is Turing machine, $ |L(M) \cap \{a,b\}|= 1\} \notin REC$

**Idea of proof:**

1. reduction from Halting problem
2. machine $M_x$ (output of reduction function) checks if on its input is $a$, saves this information
3. if $<M_h,W_h>$ (instance of HP) does not have required structure, $M_x$ rejects
4. $M_x$ simulates $M_h$ on $W_h$, if $M_h$ accepts, $M_x$ accepts if on its input it had $a$, otherwise rejects... if $M_h$ is in loop $M_x$ is in loop also

then

- $L(M) = \emptyset$ if $<M_h,W_h>$ has structure corrupted or $M_h$ is in loop on word $W_h$
- $L(M) = \{a\}$ if $<M_h,W_h>$ has correct structure and $M_h$ halts

**How I see it:**

- $M_x$ saves information of its input

  - if $M_h$ halts, $M_x$ checks saved information regarding input, if it contains $a$ or $b$ accepts, otherwise rejects

then

- $L(M) = \emptyset$ if $<M_h,W_h>$ has corrupted structure or $M_h$ is in loop on word $W_h$
- $L(M) = \{a\}$ if $<M_h,W_h>$ has correct structure and $M_h$ halts with input $a$
- $L(M) = \{b\}$ if $<M_h,W_h>$ has correct structure and $M_h$ halts with input $b$

I do not understand what happened with $b$.